# How to ignore letters using sort for numbers

Tags: linux, sort

How can I make `sort` or `awk` ignore letters while sorting using numbers in specific field? I have the following data in my text file:

```
name name space 2018
name2 name2 space (active 2020)
name1 name1 space (c. 2019)
```

I want the command to ignore the "(", ")", "c.", and "active", so it can sort the data using the year only.

I'm looking for this output:

```
name  name    space   2018
name1 name1   space   (c. 2019)
name2 name2   space   (active 2020)
```

Comment: Do we need to sort only years? or the first three fields also?

Comment: May a string resembling a year also appear somewhere else on your file's lines? Is the year always the last word?

Comment: I need to organize all columns based on the year column. The idea is to ignore non numeric (letters, special character, etc) from the field and pull the year to sort it out and display all data as appeared in the question.

Comment: How are your fields delimited?

Answer (score 4):

Extract the appropriate part of the last field and add it as a sortable field in its own right. Sort on that field. Remove the temporarily added field so that we are left with just the original data

```
awk '{y = $NF; gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "", y); printf "%s\t%s\n", y, $0}' file |
    sort -k1,1n |
    cut -f2-
```

The `gsub` contains an RE that removes all non-digit characters from the last space-separated field. You can run just the `awk` command (obviously without the trailing pipeline character) to see what it does to your input data. Then add the `sort` to see what that does.

Comment: Why `sort -k1,2n`? Note that the default `sort` field delimiter is the transition from a non-blank to a blank, not tab like in `cut`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas are you asking why I stopped the sort on field 2, or something more general? The first delimiter is a tab from `awk`'s `printf`, so `sort` can see the numeric year field I've added as well as the next field, but the `cut` can easily chop off that first temporary field. I could have separated on a space, or even a colon, but then I'd have needed to specify that character to `cut`.

Comment: `-k1,2n` selects as key the part of the line that goes from the start of the line to the second occurrence of a transition from a non-blank to a blank, and interprets it numerically, which doesn't make sense. Anything past the first transition from non-blank to blank would be ignored anyway when converting to number.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas is right. you want to sort on the 1st field, containing "y" values. Use:  `sort -k1,1n` (ie, from field 1 to 1, numerically)

Comment: Field sorting amended. My original thinking was to provide a semblance of order in the event of multiple years, but as pointed out by you both (StéphaneChazelas and OlivierDulac) I can't do that with the `n` suffix. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To sort on the right-most sequence of decimal digits on each line, you could, extract it and put it at the front, sort and strip afterwards:

```
<file LC_ALL=C sed '
  h;                    # save pattern space (current line) onto hold space
  s/[^0123456789]*$//;  # remove non-digit characters from the end
  s/^.*[^0123456789]//; # remove everything up to the last non-digit
  G;                    # append \n and hold space to pattern space
  s/\n/:/;              # replace that \n with :' |
  sort -n |
  cut -d: -f2-
```

Comment: why you didn't use `[^0-9]` for `[^0123456789]`?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas your code is the only one that worked! all other codes that were listed in the answers did not work. Thank you so much @Stéphane Chazelas! I have one more request, could you explain to me the code?                                
  _italic_ **bold** `code`                                                                                        
                                                                                                                   <file LC_ALL=C sed 'h;s/[^0123456789]*$//;s/^.*[^0123456789]//;G;s/\n/:/' |
  sort -n |
  cut -d: -f2-

Comment: @αғsнιη, with `LC_ALL=C` (added here so that `.*` matches any sequence of bytes), they should be equivalent. In other locales, there's no such guarantee and `[0-9]` often matches on many more characters than 0123456789, so now I'm trying to get used to using `[0123456789]` when I  want to match on those 10 characters only. See also [How to ensure user input consists of exactly 6 digits](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/608960)

Answer (score 2):

Applying option `-V` (natural sorting) and sorting by the first field

```
sort -Vk1,1 file

name name space 2018
name1 name1 space (c. 2019)
name2 name2 space (active 2020)
```

For some tricky cases:

```
sort -Vk1,1 -k5 file
```

After the comments, I decided to add:

```
awk 'BEGIN {PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"} {a=$0; gsub(/[^0-9]/, ""); D[a]=$0}; END {for(i in D)print i}' file
```

I transfer all the numbers to the values of the array with keys in the form of a string and specify the sort order:
`PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"`

Comment: @roaima, Yes, but the `-V` option applies globally. It may well be useful.

Comment: The first part of your answer still sorts on the first field, which isn't what the OP wanted

Comment: @roaima, If you enable the `--debug` option, it will be seen by the second underline that the sorting is done not only by the first field. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When I run into awkward sorting tasks, I find that *msort* often can handle them.

The code snippet:

```
# Utility functions: print-as-echo, print-line-with-visual-space.
pe() { for _i;do printf "%s" "$_i";done; printf "\n"; }
pl() { pe;pe "-----" ;pe "$*"; }

pl " Input data file $FILE:"
head $FILE

pl " Results, msort:"
msort -l -j -q -n -1 --comparison-type hybrid $FILE
```

produces:

```
-----
 Input data file data1:
name name space 2018
name2 name2 space (active 2020)
name0 xx2021yy
name1 name1 space (c. 2019)

-----
 Results, msort:

 name name space 2018
 name1 name1 space (c. 2019)
 name2 name2 space (active 2020)
 name0 xx2021yy
```

Briefly: omit log, quiet, each line is a record, sort on right-most field, hybrid comparison.

Run on:

```
Environment: LC_ALL = C, LANG = C
(Versions displayed with local utility "version")
OS, ker|rel, machine: Linux, 3.16.0-10-amd64, x86_64
Distribution        : Debian 8.11 (jessie) 
bash GNU bash 4.3.30
```

From the man page:

```
   -n,--position <POS>(,<POS>)
          Sort on the specified POS or contiguous range of POSs,  where  a
          POS  is  of  the  form <field number>(.<character number>). Both
          counts begin at one.  Field numbers but  not  character  numbers
          may  be negative, in which case they are counted from the right.
          Thus, 1.2 is the second character of the first  field;  -2.1  is
          the first character of the next to last field.
```

The *msort* code can be found in many repositories, here's more information:

```
msort   sort records in complex ways (man)
Path    : /usr/bin/msort
Version : 8.53
Type    : ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYS ...)
Help    : probably available with -h,--help
Repo    : Debian 8.11 (jessie) 
Home    : http://www.billposer.org/Software/msort.html (pm)
```

Best wishes ... cheers, drl

Answer (score 1):

**using Raku (formerly known as Perl 6)**

This more difficult than it looks. I started by doubling the number of lines in the test file, then thought about the best way to approach this problem.  One approach might be splitting on whitespace, however that would also split on whitespace within parentheses, thus some rows would have 4 columns, while others would have five.

The code below sorts on a 4-digit "year" regex, ignoring columns (i.e. "text fields", in the OP's parlance). The code works as long as there's only one (1) year-per-row:

```
raku -e 'my $a = lines(); my @b = $a.comb(/ \d**4 /).pairs; my $c = @b.sort(*.values)>>.keys.flat; $a[$c.flat]>>.put;' sort_year.txt
name name space 2018
name0 name space 2018
name1 name1 space (c. 2019)
name4 name1 space (c. 2019)
name2 name2 space (active 2020)
name3 name2 space (active 2020)
```

The code above combs for a 4-digit regex pattern (`@b`); an ordering index (`$c`) is derived (from `@b`), and then lines (`$a`) is reordered based on the indexing "key" (`$c`).

Here's the input file, for anyone who wants to try this at home:

```
~$ cat sort_year.txt

name name space 2018
name2 name2 space (active 2020)
name1 name1 space (c. 2019)
name0 name space 2018
name3 name2 space (active 2020)
name4 name1 space (c. 2019)
```

https://raku.org/

Answer (score 0):

command

```
awk '{sub(/)$/,"",$0);print }' filename|sort -k5| awk 'NR>1{$0=$0")"}1'
```

output

```
name name space 2018
name1 name1 space (c. 2019)
name2 name2 space (active 2020)
```